# Question about representing certain determinant in a general form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

So here is the question; it is to prove

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0&\cdots& 0&0\\0&1&1&0&\cdots& 0&0\\0&0&1&1&\cdots& 0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0&\cdots& 1&1\\1&0&0&0&\cdots& 0&1\end{bmatrix}=1+(-1)^n(-1)$$
 and the matrix is $n \times n$, and $n\ge2$.

Ok so I  started from the first column and it becomes 
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&\cdots& 0&0\\0&1&1&\cdots& 0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots &1&1\\0&0&0&\cdots& 0&1\end{bmatrix}\quad-\text{ or }+\quad \det\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&\cdots &0&0\\1&1&0&\cdots& 0&0\\0&1&1&\cdots& 0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots& 1&1\end{bmatrix}$$
Then I had difficulty to proceed, someone please help?

Comment: Use induction. Show the claim for small $n$ by hand and then in the step $n\to n+1$, you do exactly what you did right now. The resulting 2 matrices are smaller. Can you conclude anything from induction hypothesis?

Comment: The two matrices you obtain are triangular, you should know how to compute their determinant.

Comment: Alternately, you could do row operations from the bottom up by eliminating the $1$'s to the right of the diagonal.  This will either result in a $2$ in the upper left corner and $1$'s on the diagonal or a $0$ in that corner.

Comment: The penultimate number of the n-th column is not $1$ but $0$